# I typed exactly same way but my code made TypeError like this. //useState in react code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I checked my code more than 4 times and rewrited entire code. but I couldn't find any difference between Youtube code and mine.

here is the code

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './conversation.css';

export default function Conversation({conversation,currentUser}) {
    const [user,setUser] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        const friendId = conversation.members.find((m)=>m !==currentUser._id);
        
        const getUser = async ()=>{
            try{
                const res = await axios ('/users?userId='+friendId);               
                setUser(res.data);                
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err);
            }            
        };        
        getUser()               
    },[currentUser, conversation]);    

    return(
       <div className='conversation'>
        <img 
            className='conversationImg' 
            src='https://img.seoul.co.kr/img/upload/2020/05/25/SSI_20200525111945_O2.jpg'
            alt=''
        />
        <span className='conversationName'>{user.username}</span>
       </div>
    );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du8Wt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuOIp.png)

console messages

it works in Youtube practice.

Actually, I found this when i changed this

```
const [user,setUser] = useState(null); -> const [user,setUser] = useState('');
```

it worked

or

const [user,setUser] = useState(null); leave it like practice code
instead I changed

```
setUser(res.data); -> setUser(res.data.username);
<span className='conversationName'>{user.username}</span>; ->
<span className='conversationName'>{user}</span>;
```

I solves problems  can move on next but I couldn't get it.
Please explain me why origin code has caused the error.

Comment: Your `user` state starts off as `null`, so you're going to be doing `null.username` in your JSX so you get an error. The first time your `useEffect` runs is after the initial render, and it still takes some time for your asynchronous HTTP request to complete and provide you with a response. It's only once you get the response will `user` not be `null` anymore which is when its safe to use `user.username`

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.  But I'm still curious. That code and mine are exactly the same, but only my code is giving the error.

Comment: can you share the code that you are copying from? There must be a difference... or perhaps there is a mistake in the video

Comment: Above code is mine.  here is Youtube practice link. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HggSXt1Hzfk  that part starts from 57:40.  
In my eyes.. I don't have any typing mistakes.

Comment: hm, interesting. In my eyes that code should be crashing, unless react does something with caching state for hot-reloads while you're developing. I can see in the actual github repo on that vid the source code is using optional chaining (`?.`) before reading the `.username` property - which you can see [here](https://github.com/safak/youtube/blob/chat-app/client/src/components/conversations/Conversation.jsx). Maybe he fixes it later on in the video (just checked, he fixes it at [1:03:10](https://youtu.be/HggSXt1Hzfk?t=3790))